# Symfony 4 - ServiceCircularReferenceException

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am currently porting our Symfony application to Symfony 4.3. I understand from the documentation that instead of doing `$this->container->get ( 'service_a' )` the new best practice is to use Dependency Injection to attach the service in the constructor like so:

```
    public function __construct(ServiceA $service_a)
    {
        $this->service_a = $service_a;
    }
```

I have two services that in certain functions call each other, ServiceA and ServiceB. When I added ServiceA to ServiceB's constructor I saw no error but after adding ServiceB to ServiceA's constructor I received the following error:

```
(1/1) ServiceCircularReferenceException
Circular reference detected for service "App\Service\ServiceA", path: "App\Service\ServiceA -> App\Service\ServiceB -> App\Service\ServiceA".
```

(All of this code worked without issue in Symfony 2)

Have I misunderstood the new methodology? Am I using DependencyInjection wrong here?

Comment: You need to break your circular dependency. It doesn't make sense that A depends on B and B depends on A. There is something amiss in your design, and using better practices is exposing that issue.

Comment: Do those services have to depend on each other? I would say circular dependency might indicate flawed design. Is there a chance to split one (or both) of those services into smaller parts, to break the circle?

Comment: Sometimes the function you need form the other service can actually be called as a "static" function. so like theClass::myFunction() instead of $service->myFunction() (Depends on the function off course). If you could make it a "static" function (just add the word "static") then you don't need to call the entire service to reach it. Don't forget to look for other places that use that function and switch to calling it directly with :: ... It often helped me in the past, maybe it can be a solution for you too

Comment: Why exactly is it bad design for two libraries to want each others functionality? (So far it sounds like an arbitrary constraint "just because".) This was very acceptable in the S2/S3 days when the service container would be injected to a lot of your own service libraries, each going through the container asking for other services.